# JQueryMobile wrap data-role="content" div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'd like to show some static borders around the `data-role="content"` element.

```
<div data-role="page" id="moodle" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>MyPage</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        Some Content
    </div>
</div>
```

To accomplish this I am currently wrapping my page contents in a bunch of divs, which create the borders via css. These divs only have borders at top and left.

```
$(document).bind("ready",function(){
$('div[data-role="content"]').each(function(k,v){
    $(v).wrap('<div class="b1"/>');
    $(v).wrap('<div class="b2"/>');
    $(v).wrap('<div class="b3"/>');
    $(v).wrap('<div class="b4"/>');
    $(v).wrap('<div class="content"/>');
});
```

The problem is that, when scrolling the content, the top border vanishes as it scrolls out of the viewport / behind the header. So how to "wrap" the `data-role="content"`-div into my other divs to make sure the borders stay fixed while the content is scrolling?

EDIT:
Example of the upper left corner of the content div (just right below the header). This borders should stay fixed while scrolling:
[image: Example image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add borders to elements that persist in their location while the content scrolls behind them.

For an example pseudo-page like this:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-position="fixed" data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-position="fixed" data-role="footer">
        <h2>Footer</h2>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Can have CSS like this applied:

```
.ui-page .ui-header {
    box-sizing    : border-box;
    border-bottom : 4px solid red;
}
.ui-page .ui-footer {
    box-sizing : border-box;
    border-top : 4px solid red;
}
.ui-mobile .ui-page {
    box-sizing   : border-box;
    border-left  : 4px solid red !important;
    border-right : 4px solid red !important;
}
```

Which places a border at the bottom of the header, the top of the footer, and the left/right sides of the content area.

The `box-sizing : border-box;` declarations are to make the calculations less complicated (it includes the border/padding within the height/width dimensions of the element).

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2M5Jc/

Docs for `box-sizing`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing

If you don't want a fixed position header or footer, you can just place an element in their place that has zero height and a border.

Comment: Everything fine. But I have to add multiple borders to my content div. E.g. think of a rainbow going from the lower left -> top left -> top right side of the content div. That's the reason why I'am using this massive amount of divs. Edited my post and provided an example how it has to look like.

Comment: @k_wave take a look at CSS `border-image`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-image

Comment: border-image did the job - despite the fact that it's more expensive than div borders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the content inside #content scrollable

http://outof.me/native-scrolling-in-jquery-mobilephonegap-applications

That way your borders will stay where they are, but the content inside will scroll

**UPDATE - example:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="moodle" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>MyPage</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content" class="scrollable">
        Some Content
    </div>
</div>


div[data-role="content"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 41px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

/* iOS specific fix, don't use it on Android devices */
.scrollable > * {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```

Comment: This does nothing more than the native `data-position="fixed"` of jqm. Anyway, I can't see how this solves my problem.

Comment: @k_wave - Read the blog post again. Yes, data-position="fixed" is for the headers and yes, you will probably want to apply that - but that's not the point. The point is in making the content inside of #content scrollable, i.e. `overflow-y: scroll` && `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`   If you do that, then the content will scroll, but the borders will stay in place.